# Mosquitto bridge CPU consumption increases with time

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, aws-iot, bridge

We have set a bridge using mosquitto which connects to AWS IoT broker. Our system only uses QoS 0 topic subscriptions. We have noticed that the consumption ofCPU increases with time indicated with an ever increasing slope in the CPU usage graph. It start from around 43% and reaches upto 70% in 24 hours. What are the factors or settings that can play a role in excessive CPU consumption. We have disabled persistence, disabled logs and have also disabled updates from $SYS topic. MQTTV311 is being used. Mosquitto version is 1.6.8 and the bridge is hosted on an z1d large type machine which allows 4 GHZ processing speed within single core. We used this machine because of mosquitto's incapability to completely use the CPU power due to non-scalability (single threadedness).

Comment: Is the number of connected clients and message rate constant?

Comment: You have a Mosquitto up on AWS, but also using AWS IoT Broker?!?  Why not just skip Mosquitto and just use the AWS IoT Broker?!?